# youmax plugin to display multiple channel playlists

Tags: javascript, html, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-channels

Im using youmax plugin to display videos from one channel, now i want to display the 3 channel playlists in one page for html site. is it possible to duplicate the function to display multiple channels on one page.
Reference for plugin :

[link is here for that plugin](http://bitconfig.com/youmax/bitconfig_youmax.html)

any help Thanks..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiple channel playlist has not developed yet in this plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you can do -

1. Make 3 Tabs on your page each for a channel
2. Create 3 containers for youmax each displaying a playlist you like
3. Code your Tabs to display a particular Youmax container on click